# card flip doesn't work in IE (11, 10, etc)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transform, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I found this tutorial by David Desandro on CSS3 transform but found that his code doesn't work in IE...

http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/card-02-slide-flip.html

Note that when "flip" is clicked, the only thing that happens is that Card 1 is still shown and card 2 is hidden...Anyone know what's going on and have a fix for this?

here is the code that he used for this effect

```
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 260px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
     -moz-perspective: 800px;
       -o-perspective: 800px;
          perspective: 800px;
}

#card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
       -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
          transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
     -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right center;
     -moz-transform-origin: right center;
       -o-transform-origin: right center;
          transform-origin: right center;
}

#card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: translateX( -100% ) rotateY( -180deg );
     -moz-transform: translateX( -100% ) rotateY( -180deg );
       -o-transform: translateX( -100% ) rotateY( -180deg );
          transform: translateX( -100% ) rotateY( -180deg );
}

#card figure {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 260px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
       -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#card .front {
  background: red;
}

#card .back {
  background: blue;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
     -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
       -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
          transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question.

Comment: The link contains the relevant code. is this really necessary?

Comment: Yes, it's necessary: "`With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.`" [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about). Links tend to rot, and if your question lacks code, the question and answers are not usefull for future visitors. How about the JS?

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer does not currently support the CSS transform property 'preserve-3d', which is why the demo does not work. However, 'preserve-3D' is currently one of the features [in development](http://status.modern.ie/csstransformspreserve3d).

You can read about Preserve-3D here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transforms/#transform-style-property

If you are interested in finding out any other features the IE team is currently working on, check out: http://status.modern.ie/

Comment: Thanks! I realized this too after looking into it a bit more. I am still interested if someone has produced a solution for this.